# Is this query correct?

Tags: trigger, soql, case-object

```
Case oldRequestownerid=[SELECT OwnerId 
                        FROM case 
                        WHERE OwnerId =: Trigger.oldMap.get(d.Id).OwnerId
                       ];
```

This query is written inside a trigger after update on case.
Requirement is to send email when owner of a record is changed.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check changes in fields of the records being updated, you do not need to issue queries. Instead, you can directly use the information the trigger provides you. Something like this:

```
if(Trigger.isUpdate)
{
  for(Case c : Trigger.new)
  {
    Case oldC = Trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id);
    if(c.OwnerId != oldC.OwnerId)
      <Do something>
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of the below code

```
Case oldRequestownerid=[select OwnerId from case where OwnerId =: Trigger.oldMap.get(d.Id).OwnerId];
```

Can you plz write the code and try again

```
List<Case> oldRequestownerid=[select OwnerId from case where OwnerId =: Trigger.oldMap.get(d.Id).OwnerId];
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.